# Drawing on UIScrollView and UIImageView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I want to draw line on image view then image view is to put on scroll view. How to do that? Any Idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the scroll view's contents to a UIView.  Display the image in the UIView, do a setNeedsDisplay on that view, and draw anything you want when the UIView's drawRect gets called.